# Pressurized Tank with compressed air

Tags: thermodynamics

How does ambient temperature affects the pressure of the tank filled with compressed air?

Comment: Do you mean the temperature of the compressed air?

Comment: No. I am pressure testing a bolted tank and i pressurize it with compressor.
I just wanted to know how does temperature affect the pressure inside the tank. if there will be a significant change if temprerature changes

Answer (score 0):

If you've ever scuba dived you'll know that the pressure in a tank falls as it cools down to ambient after filling, and you're advised never to leave the filled tank in a hot car. You can use the ideal gas law from thermodynamics to calculate the proportionality of pressure and absolute temperature in the circumstance of constant volume and constant number of gas molecules. But pressure testing is potentially very unsafe, so it's worth seeking professional advice in person.